# Is there a regular expression that allows trailing spaces for a word with fixed size?

Tags: regex, context-free-grammar

We have some fields with user input; and so far our rule to validate this content was `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,7}`. 
Meaning: any uppercase word with at least one character; starting with a character; and up to 8 characters for the whole word.

Now I am told that we should accept "trailing" spaces as well; but of course - only trailing spaces. Update; as the first answer got that wrong: the maximum length of the whole word is still 8 characters! Because that is exactly the point that caused me to ask this question.

I guess this can be checked with TWO expressions:
a) `[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]{0,7}`... must match the input and
b) `[ ][A-Z0-9]` must not match the input

(the second expression simply finding any "non-trailing" space)

But is there also a SINGLE regular expression that I could use to check for this condition?

Or is this one of the occasions, where well, though luck - regular expressions only accept context free grammars?!

Comment: But you don't actually want to capture the spaces as input, do you? I'd trim the input of all leading and trailing whitespace, and *then* apply your existing validator.

Comment: Hmm ok, via your updates, I see that you *do* want to capture the spaces. Never mind. That's a weird requirement! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allow trailing spaces only then use:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,7} *$
```

Or:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,7}\h*$
```

Here `\h*` is horizontal whitespace that matches 0 or space or tab characters at the end only.

---

**EDIT:** Based on edited question you can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9\h]{1,8}$)[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\h*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL0iU8/1)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't precise: even with trailing whitespaces - no more than 8 characters overall. So "A234567 " (9 chars!) is not allowed; but "A1234   " is.

Comment: ok yes that wasn't clear in question, can you please edit the question with this info. Meanwhile I am updating the answer.